# possibly speed up matrix multiplications in loop

Tags: python, numpy, loops, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I asked a question here with the details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4381785/possibly-speed-up-matrix-multiplications

In short, I am trying to create a P x N matrix, X, with typical element: \sum_{j,k;j,k \neq i} w_{jp} A_{jk} Y_{kp}, where w is P x N, A is N x N and Y is P x N. See the link above for a markup version of that formula.

I'm providing a mwe here to see how I can correct the code (the calculations seem correct, just incomplete see below) and more importantly **speed** this up however possible:

```
w = np.array([[2,1],[3,7]])
A = np.array([[2,1],[9,-1]])
Y = np.array([[6,2],[11,8]])
N=w.shape[1]
P=w.shape[0]
X = np.zeros((P, N))
for p in range(P) :
    for i in range(N-1):
        for j in range(N-1):
            X[p,i] = np.delete(w,i,1)[i,p]*np.delete(np.delete(A,i,0),i,1)[i,j]*np.delete(Y.T,i,0)[j,p]
```

The output looks like:

```
array([[  -2. ,    0. ],
       [-56. ,     0.]])
```

If we set (i,p) = to the (1,1) element of X_{ip}, the value can be understood using the formula provided above:

sum_{j,k;j,k \neq i} w_{j1} A_{jk} Y_{k1} = w_12 A_22 Y_12 = 1 * -1 * 2 = -2 as it is in the output.

the (1,2) element of X_{ip}  should be:
sum_{j,k;j,k \neq i} w_{j2} A_{jk} Y_{k2} = w_22 A_22 Y_22 = 7 * -1 * 8 = -56 as it is in the output.

But I am not getting the correct answer for the final column of X because my `range` is to `(N-1)` not `N` because I received an `IndexError` out of bounds when it is `N`. More importantly, here N=P=2, but I have large N and P and the code, as is, takes a very long time to run. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix`.  And don't use `np.delete`; using indexing instead.  It's hard to visualize the calculation with that pseudo-math display.

Comment: Besides hpaulj's comment, you state that N=P=2, but a quick look at your example shows that N=3. So you need to sit down and understand the dimensions before you access them.

Comment: Why do you use the `@` operator in the MathExchange post, but `*` here?  `@` works with `np.matrix` as well, so will make your code clearer even if you don't take my suggestion to use `np.array`.  On the surface this looks something like `w@A@Y.T`, but you have the complication of omitting some sort of 'diagonal' values.

Comment: @user3328152 I forgot to update that part, it is updated now.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks I was writing some R code earlier and my brain just wrote matrix without thinking. updated to np.array()

Comment: @hpaulj I matrix multiply AY.T outside the loop over there. I agree that it feels simple on the surface. I was hoping I'm just missing something obvious or clever. The problem with w@A@Y.T is that the resulting object is T x T not T x N.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `delete` functions depend only on `i`, I factored them out, and reordered the loops.  Also corrected the `w1` index order.

```
In [274]: w = np.array([[2,1],[3,7]])
     ...: A = np.array([[2,1],[9,-1]])
     ...: Y = np.array([[6,2],[11,8]])
     ...: N=w.shape[1]
     ...: P=w.shape[0]
     ...: X = np.zeros((P, N))
     ...: for i in range(N-1):
     ...:     print('i',i)
     ...:     w1 = np.delete(w,i,1)
     ...:     a1 = np.delete(np.delete(A,i,0),i,1)
     ...:     y1 = np.delete(Y.T,i,0)
     ...:     print(w1.shape, a1.shape, y1.shape)
     ...:     print(w1@a1@y1)
     ...:     print(np.einsum('ij,jk,li->i',w1,a1,y1))
     ...:     for p in range(P):
     ...:         for j in range(N-1):
     ...:             X[p,i] = w1[p,i]*a1*y1[j,p]
     ...: 
i 0
(2, 1) (1, 1) (1, 2)
[[ -2  -8]
 [-14 -56]]
[ -2 -56]
In [275]: X
Out[275]: 
array([[ -2.,   0.],
       [-56.,   0.]])
```

Your [-2,-56] are the diagonal of `w1@a1@y1`, or the `einsum`.  The 0's are from the original `np.zeros` because `i` is only on `range(1)`.

This should be faster because the `delete` is not repeated unnecessarily.  `np.delete` is still relatively expensive, but I haven't tried to figure out exactly what you are doing.

Didn't your question initially have `(2,3)` and `(3,3)` arrays?  That, or something a bit larger, may be more general and informative.

## edit

I think this is closer to the math expressions:

```
def foo(w,A,Y):
    P, N = w.shape
    X = np.zeros((P, N))
    for i in range(N):
         #w1 = np.delete(w,i,1)
         a1 = np.delete(A,i,1)
         y1 = np.delete(Y.T,i,0)
         print(w1.shape, a1.shape, y1.shape)
         for p in range(P) :
              for j in range(N-1):
                   X[p,i] += w[p,i]*a1[i,j]*y1[j,p]
    return X
```

we can get rid of the `j` loop with:

```
def foo1(w,A,Y):
    P, N = w.shape
    X = np.zeros((P, N))
    for i in range(N):
         a1 = np.delete(A,i,1)
         y1 = np.delete(Y.T,i,0)
         print(w1.shape, a1.shape, y1.shape)
         for p in range(P) :
             X[p,i] = w[p,i]*np.dot(a1[i,:],y1[:,p])
    return X
```

with

```
 ...:     w3 = np.array([[2,1,0],[3,7,0.5]])
 ...:     A3 = np.array([[2,1,0],[9,0,8],[1,2,5]])
 ...:     Y3 = np.array([[6,2,-1],[11,8,-7]])
 ...:     w2 = np.array([[2,1],[3,7]])
 ...:     A2 = np.array([[2,1],[9,-1]])
 ...:     Y2 = np.array([[6,2],[11,8]])
```

both produce

```
In [372]: foo(w2,A2,Y2)
(2, 1) (2, 1) (1, 2)
...
Out[372]: 
array([[  4.,  54.],
       [ 24., 693.]])
In [373]: foo(w3,A3,Y3)
(2, 1) (3, 2) (2, 2)
...
Out[373]: 
array([[  4. ,  46. ,   0. ],
       [ 24. , 301. ,  13.5]])
```

and after more fiddling:

```
def foo4(w,A,Y):
    P, N = w.shape
    X = np.zeros((P, N))
    for i in range(N):
         a1 = np.delete(A,i,1)
         y1 = np.delete(Y.T,i,0)
         X[:,i] = np.einsum('j,jp->p',a1[i,:],y1)    
         # X[:,i] = a1[i,:]@y1
    return X*w
```

I suspect it is possible to do `w*(A@Y.T)` and then subtract an array that involves `A[:,i]` and `Y[:,i]`, but haven't figured out that array.

Comment: for N > 2, I think your line X[p,i] = ... should have the bit you have inside an np.sum(), right?

Comment: otherwise it raises a `ValueError`

Comment: to get the full range, should I implement a try/except and in the except clause shift i -> i-1 and j -> j-1 everywhere? I can time them, but I think your solution is indeed faster.

Comment: If the correction of X[p,i] = np.sum(w1[p,i]*a1*y1[j,p])  to your answer is correct your solution is slightly slower than the original for N=300 and P=50. Moreover, the final answers don't coincide.

Comment: Where's your `np.sum`?  I'm still trying to understand what you are doing. Notation on the other site is a bit better, but still not that clear.  Did you mean to use `X[p,i] += ...` in the `j` loop?

Comment: In the math expressions, you use `k \neq i` where `k` only occurs in `A` and `Y`, but in the `numpy` code you do a `delete` on `w`, two dimensions of `A`, and `Y`.